# Not able to link github private repository to jcenter in bintray

Tags: android, gradle, bintray, jcenter

I published my project in the Bintray successfully, but when I tried to link it to the jCenter, I got this error message:

> Failed to send a message: The version control
>   "https://github-private-repository-url" returns 404.

My GitHub repository is private, so I want to know is it possible to link a private repo to the jCenter, and if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JFrog Bintray Documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Importing+from+GitHub) :

> Note that private repositories in GitHub are only displayed and
>   available for importing by Bintray users with Premium Plan accounts
>   who also have "Access private repositories" permissions in GitHub.

Generally, to publish a private repository, you will need a repository manager like [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/artifactory/) or [Nexus Repository](https://www.sonatype.com/product-nexus-repository). You can either maintain your own repository server or avail cloud solutions offered by such repository managers to host your artifacts.

One can also read off directly from GitHub private repository. [JitPack Private Package Repository](https://jitpack.io/private) can be used to directly expose GitHub private repositories to publish private Maven, Gradle and Android libraries. You can also expose source code in your private Github repositories without versioning provided by Jitpack as explained in this [Medium article](https://medium.com/widgetlabs-engineering/using-a-maven-repository-in-a-private-github-repository-with-gradle-46ab73f198a6). Also, these approaches need you to share your GitHub repo tokens.

Comment: is there any way to link GitHub private repository to jcenter in bintray?

Comment: You can take a look at https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/BT/Importing+from+GitHub

From this doc - Note that private repositories in GitHub are only displayed and available for importing by Bintray users with Premium Plan accounts who also have "Access private repositories" permissions in GitHub.

Comment: follow my answer no need to go for a premium, alll you need to is setup maven repository and publish your library(SDK).

Comment: This is a private repo Arul! Question doesn’t exist if repo is public.

Answer (score 1):

For Publishing library in JCENTER you need to make your repository as public.

If you want to publish your library without changing public.

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en

Follow this thread.